# How to get item within a list to simple statement with dynamic index in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, list, apache-camel, pojo

I have the following problem:
I'm able to get the data I want to use as POJOS through the following way:

```
something().unmarshal(new ListJacksonDataFormat(SomePOJO.class))
.to("direct:processThis")
```

Now I would like to use some of the data in the POJO's in the following way (inject the values to custom header as query string params, pseudocode):

```
from("direct:processThis")
        .transform().constant("Something as a response")
        .setHeader("Someheader", simple("http://xyz.someplace.com?someparam={${body[get the index here].location.coordinates[1].toString()}}"))
```

How do I dynamically inject the index, from which I want to read the data? Do I have to create a custom processor for this extraction and converting of the double values or is there a some more "Camelish" style to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get the point of your question.

You can take the index from any "storage" you can access with the [Simple language](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html). The most common are message headers and Exchange properties.

```
${header.foo}
${exchangeProperty.bar}
```